# GitHub unable to insert personal token unable

Tags: github

I have activated the Two Factor recovery mode and created a personal token access on github to clone push, pull and fetch with access to my repo. However I am not able to type my created personal token when the Password is requested. In my terminal, as explained below, a KEY SYMBOL appears that doesn't allow me to type the token. Am I doing anything weird ?

```
(base) myname@myname-MBP Tesco % git push
Username for 'https://github.com': myusername
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git/'

(base) myname@myname-MBP myrepo % git push
Username for 'https://github.com': myusername
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com': KEYSYMBOL
```

Comment: try ssh instead of https.

Comment: thanks, exuse me how can access via ssh on terminal?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh check this

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam all set. Thanks! it works great